# Secondary hard drive disappears after sleep

Tags: windows-10, laptop

All problem solutions I found didn't fit my case below.

I own a Lenovo E50 laptop with Windows10. The other day I bought an SSD drive and put it in Sata0 (main drive slot), then swapped a CDROM drive with the HDD, and so now the HDD is in Sata1 slot instead of the CDROM.

The issue that I have is that after I resume the computer from sleep, that second hard drive most of the time doesn't get detected and I have to repeat the sleep-resume cycle until it appears, or reboot the system.

I imagine that the cause is HDD's slow spin-up time (system resumes faster than the HDD can spin up). No disk manager can see the drive, "Intel Rapid Storage" program can't see the drive - it's like the drive isn't even connected... Rescan in disk manager doesn't detect it either.

I have tried all the solutions I could find, but none worked, and I also tried switching up drives, but then my computer didn't even boot up.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug of the BIOS/UEFI to me. A slept / spun down drive shouldn't disappear fron Disk Management. Also it shouldn't happen after the system is awaken from suspension, since that should "power up" everything again.

Comment: Yeah, I know... logically that is how it should be. I had updated BIOS to the very latest, but it still haven't fixed it.
As for HDD sleeping - that isn't the case. When you sleep the computer the hard drive is spun down. But when you wake up, it doesn't spin up fast enough (my theory) or power to that port doesn't get sent... idk. Because I tried sleeping my computer while the drive was spinning - on resume it didn't appear.

Answer (score 5):

I just kept reading all solutions and nothing worked out for me . There are 3 solutions i found .

1. Restart the computer
2. Install Intel RST driver
3. Control panel > Power option > Advanced setting > Hard drive> Turn off hard drive > Make it never by entering value (o) .

Comment: After installing the Intel Rapid Storage Technology, my drive wakes up as expected after sleep. While before it was missing after every sleep.

Comment: Me too ! "After installing the Intel Rapid Storage Technology, my drive wakes up as expected after sleep.".  I had this issue after a Windows 10 update on april 29th 2019. Maybe the Intel RST installation revert a setting back to what it was before the Windows 10 update.  If it's that, I wonder which setting it is.

Answer (score 0):

Having recently experienced this problem and tried for weeks to fix it I think I have one possible solution.

My experience

- Windows 10 home, Ryzen 1700, Gigabyte Gaming 3 mobo, with Samsung 650 500GB SSD as main (boot) drive and an old  2.5” 1TB laptop hard drive (internal) as second storage drive. All worked perfectly well. I had Samsung Magician installed and it was set to the maximum reliability setting rather than high performance.
- Swapped 2.5” to a 3.5” Western Digital Blue (a LOT faster than the 2.5”) and I start to experience wake up from sleep issues. WD blue disappears but only after a long (many hours) sleep. Short sleeps were fine.
- When I swapped to the WD drive I also did the following (1) moved desktop and docs to D drive (2) purchased Acronis True Image and used it to back up files and OS to D. I do not think these were the problem despite other users reporting that they might be.

  At first I thought my cabling was loose but that never fixed things. Tried several of the OS suggestions in the forums. No luck. Noticed in some users mentioned both Samsung Magician and Acronis.

  Eventually I got the latest update to Acronis and also removed Samsung Magician from start up. Within Magic I changed to high performance setting as well. This altered something on virtual memory and “hibernation” mode – basically reverting them to standard Windows settings.

Since then my system has worked fine. My suspicion is that this is down to either the switch from reliability to high performance OR removing Magican from running in the background on startup.

This still allows my system to sleep completely and all the WD drive stops spinning – power consumption drops to under 1W.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've finally solved it.

Tried pretty much everything, including BIOS/driver updates, different versions of RST, complete Windows reinstall, etc. with no luck.

What ultimately did the trick for me is creating a new storage pool (you can do it with just one drive, with no fault tolerance of course): https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/12438/windows-10-storage-spaces

The disk will have to be wiped though, and it doesn't always go smoothly (can give weird access errors if it's already formatted) - in my case I had to uninstall RST, delete all partitions ***and reboot*** before it went through.

The drive is still present in the "safely remove hardware" list in the tray which is a bit annoying, but no more disconnects on wakeup (so far).

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This Fixed for me Fianlly , use the command prompt method , after that Try setting the AHCI Link Power Management to HIPM+DIPM under Advanced Settings for Power Options

https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/o6etw2/comment/h2tdjpn/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1189020)

Answer (score -1):

Open Intel RST -> Performance -> Disable: Link Power Management

Comment: To make this an *answer*, be explicit: How does one open Intel RST? Show images, if helpful.